# How to add a custom JWT engine to a .NET 6.0 project

Tags: c#, rest, .net-6.0

Admittedly, I am new to creating RESTful services. I have created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project. I have the main part of the REST service created, but I need to add authentication. For this app, I cannot use Microsoft's Identity package.

I have found a JWT Authentication article that seems to work well for me, but it's implemented as a console program--there's no information on how to wire it into a Web API project (facepalm). [JWT Authentication using C#](https://medium.com/@mmoshikoo/jwt-authentication-using-c-54e0c71f21b0)

I have done a lot of looking on the net, but I can't seem to find what I need.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This is simply too broad to be answered on Stack Overflow and should be closed as such. That said, there are several ways to wire in JWTs, depending on your goal. You can leverage ASP.NET middleware for authentication handlers, you can add filters, or you could even add boilerplate to every controller.

Comment: What's wrong with built-in AddJwtBearer? Why you can't use it?

Comment: @DavidL, any suggestions on making this question better would be appreciated. My issue seems to be when I find an article on HOW to do it, it appears to be outdate, geared for MVC, etc., and I can't seem to get it to work. That's why I posted this question with specifically what environment I am looking at. I'm sure there are many ways of getting this done, I just need to find some good samples.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, Maybe nothing. I'm so overwhelmed with the information out there, most of which seems to be geared towards older technologies because it was written years ago. And, for example, if I just look up AddJwtBearer and get the Microsoft docs, it's just definitions, no examples. It doesn't tell me how to wire up this custom authentication engine.

Comment: Why would you wire a custom jwt engine if the provided one is good? A school assignment? I believe we miss the actual issue here.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, no not a school assignment. Will the provided one let me query our own identity tables for the authentication then? NOT Microsoft's identity system, but our legacy system that I need to use.

Comment: JWT is not about querying. It just gives you the user name. The very same user name you write there when you create the token. What you do with the user name is another story. Note that not only user name but other claims can be stored in jwt but still, it's you who create claims and you who read them. I start to believe you believe jwt middleware and identity server/identity db context must always be used together. But they don't have to.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, "I start to believe you believe jwt middleware ..." Yeah, you're probably right. Back to square one. Like I said, I'm new to Web APIs and REST. Thanks.

Comment: @Jim: this is possibly helpful, [a tutorial of mine](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2022/01/net-6-webapi-with-jwt-bearer-token.html). It shows how to create a token freely and then how to validate it and get the username at the server side but it's only about jwt, no identity server, no database. The demo is split into two and it's a console app that creates the token but think of it as "anyone who knows the secret can create the token, in particular it could be the very same app that creates and consumes servers".

Comment: @WiktorZychla, yes, this was a help. Thank you. Now I just need to figure out a way of getting this to work with Swagger for my testing.  Again, thank you for taking some time with me on this.